# Select form of post categories on a post blog

Tags: wordpress

i would like to have a blog layout and on top a select form for my post categories. How can this be implemented?
Should i make a custom blog layout or is there a plugin doing this?
I have a pic showing this on a site
[image: Blog layout of posts with selecting category option]

any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to filter blog according to assigned category using category form?

WordPress Provided default widget for category filter you just assign widget and print that using `dynamic_sidebar` at index.php file which file call when you open blog. But please assign you home page and blog page at admin setting panel.

Comment: Girish, thank you for your reply! I think i don't realize what you mean but i will try to find more info about this!